# Can a C header file only specify a name of another header file

Tags: c

I found a [pacman project](https://github.com/Alexpux/MSYS2-pacman) in github where a file `conf.c` includes a header file `#include "ini.h"` where `ini.h` contains only a single line (i.e no `#include` statement):

//ini.h

```
../common/ini.c
```

I have never seen anyone doing this before! It seems a bit hackish/rough around the edges. My questions are:

- Is this legal C?
- Is it portable?
- Is it recommended?

I would have assumed the answer should be no for all these questions, but I may be learning something new...

> edit

From the answers, I see its a Linux symlink. I guess that this means it is not portable to Windows, and would also make it more difficult to read outside a unix environment. I would also imagine that using relative paths (or include directories) instead of symlinks would be a better practice in cases like this for reasons mentioned above...

Comment: Where is `conf.c` in the repository?

Comment: A symlink perhaps? What OS are you on?

Comment: I found it and the site indicates that it is a symbolic link. https://github.com/Alexpux/MSYS2-pacman/blob/master/src/pacman/ini.h

Comment: Thanks. It makes sense that its a symlink. I opened it in Windows, which didn't recognize it as a symlink. I was wondering if the compiler would interpret it correctly under these conditions.

Comment: @BryanJarmain No, I guess the compiler won't interpret it as expected, will simply include the path to the code and will fail. I have faced this problem before. Although this method may not good, you can copy the specified file manually as workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`src/pacman/ini.h`](https://github.com/Alexpux/MSYS2-pacman/blob/master/src/pacman/ini.h) is a symbolic link according to the site.

Symbolic link has an information of where the target file is (path name), and I guess it is what is displayed on the site.

The OS will redirect access to that `ini.h` to [`../common/ini.h`](https://github.com/Alexpux/MSYS2-pacman/blob/master/src/common/ini.h), which is a normal C code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any reason why not. The `include` statement indicates the compiler to replace that line with the whatever is in the included file